# Asp.Net Core Identity - Authorize attribute with roles and caching?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a simple web application in ASP.Net Core with ASP.Net core Identity.  I'm using role based authorization on various controllers and it seems to me that the `Authorize` attribute is not picking up changes to role membership right way.

Let's say I decorate a controller with the authorize attribute and specify a role, like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "TestRole")]
```

Then I log in as a user which is not in that role.  I try to access the controller and the Authorize attribute correctly prevents me to access the controller - gives me an access denied error.

Then I add the user to the TestRole programmatically (I have built a simple user management GUI in the web app where I can manage users and roles).  According to the `GetRolesAsync()` method, the user has successfully been added to the role and everything looks good if I check the records in the Identity tables in the DB.  However, I still cannot access the controller - the `Authorize` attribute does not seem to be aware that the user is now in this role.  The role information seems to be cached.  If I wait long enough before trying again (a few hours maybe) then this appears to work correctly.  If I kill the IIS express process and restart the website, this works immediately, suggesting that the role information is somehow being cached.

I have not been able to find anything which explicitly states that the Role information is indeed cached or how to disable it for that matter.  When I change the role membership of users in my system I need the changes to be reflected right away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - how typical.  I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a few days now and as soon as I finally post a question to SO, I find the answer :)

> By default, ASP.Net Identity stores user's authorized roles inside
>   Role Claim after user successful login. Those claims are stored inside
>   cookie until user logout or close the browser.

[Is it possible to cache authorizations in ASP.NET MVC & Identity 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661828/is-it-possible-to-cache-authorizations-in-asp-net-mvc-identity-2-0)

Comment: So how did you disable the cache? The link states the the Role Claim caches the credential by default until the browser is closed or cookie expires, is there a way to force it to not cache or change the cache timeout to it doesn't cache at all?